# Couldnt find any solution to change the value of a key in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jobs

I am new to jenkins pipeline.

I have a file ../../file.json

and it got two objects, each object got 4 key:value pair.
my requirement is to update two values from each object where the KEY is unique.

any suggestions please.

Comment: Could you please try to explain this with an example.

Comment: { 
"Myobj1": {
 "KEY1": "Value1", 
"KEY2": "Value2", 
"KEY3": "Value3", 
"KEY4": "Value4" 
}, 
"Myobj2": {
 "KEY1": "Value1", 
"KEY2": "Value2", 
"KEY3": "Value3
}